# How to match all specific strings inside square brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match single quotes inside square bracket.

I have to match all the single quotes inside `[item:` and `]` in the whole string to remove them.

Here are some cases:

DO NOT Remove Quotes from:

- 'text'
- ['text']

Remove ALL quotes from:

- [item:'test']

Example:

1. `[test 'item']` should stay as it is.
2. `[item: 'item']` becomes `[item: item]`
3. `['test'][item: first 'test']` becomes `['test'][item: first test]`
4. `[item: some 'random' text]` becomes `[item: some random text]`
5. `[item: 'test 'text 'random' quote']` becomes `[item: test text random quote]`

NOTE: The quotes are not in pairs. Can be odd number of quotes.

Comment: What do you want to do after matching all singlequotes like you want?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I need to remove them, but only the quotes inside the brackets

Comment: As you are a new SO user, I'll suggest you to please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it helps others and in turn they can help you back, else your post may be downvoted (although I didn't downvote your post) and closed.

Comment: And if I understand your post, you can use this regex `'(?=[^[\]]*\])` and replace the matching quotes inside square brackets with empty string. [Check this Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ixM1ZD/1)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I have formatted the question for better understanding. The problem is not solved however. Please check out the changed question.

Comment: A regex cannot _replace_, you should indicate the language or tool you are using. and as @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi said, I'd suggest you read those [so] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more samples added, the problem is clearer now.

Just to rephrase the problem, you want to match bracketed expression only that starts with `item:` and get rid of any of the singlequotes within the bracketed expression.

You can use this regex to match and capture the data in groups excluding any of the single quotes,

```
(\[item:)|(?!^)\G([^'\n]*)'+
```

and replace with appropriately captured groups which is `\1\2`

**Explanation:**

- `(\[item:)` - Start by matching `[item:` literally and captures it in group1
- `|` - Alternation
- `(?!^)\G` - Matches end of previous match position
- `([^'\n]*)` - Matches any optional text not containing singlequote or newline and captures it in group2 (you can remove `\n` though as normally it won't be part of your input text)
- `'+` - Matches one or more singlequotes which get removed as they aren't captured in any group.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Qf6br/2)**

Comment: No, but the quotes are not in pairs. There can be any number of quotes.

Comment: @MayankPhadke: But each of your sample shows it has two quotes. So you want this `[item: 'abc]` to also become `[item: abc]`? Even that is very simple to do but as none of your samples had that, I thought you always wanted to replace quotes surrounding the words.

Comment: @MayankPhadke: As you want to allow even single quotes to be replaced, the regex becomes even simpler. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/6Qf6br/2) Let me know if this works fine, so I can update my answer with this regex.

Answer (score 0):

This regex could capture the group containing brackets. Then you only have to delete containing brackets depending on the language you are using.

```
\[item:[^\]']*('[^']+')[^]]*]
```

[See live example](https://regex101.com/r/SxmGqf/2)

Comment: The thing is, i want to match only the quotes. It is not necessary that there is a pair. I need to remove ALL the quotes. Let me add another case...